# Sequential searching of a database

Tags: python, loops, search

Here is a part of some code I am having a problem with:

```py
def func():
    for i in range(len(titleList)):
        print titleList[i] + ' -- ' + artistList[i] + ' -- ' + albumList[i] + ' --',
        print yearList[i] + ' -- ' + commentList[i]

def sequentialSearch(albumList, item):
    pos = 0
    found = False
    while pos < len(albumList) and not found:
        if albumList[pos] == item:
            found = True
        else:
            pos = pos + 1
    return found

num = input("What would you like to do?\n1. Print all the contents of the database\n2. Find all the songs on a particular album\n3. Quit\nPlease Enter 1, 2, or 3: ")
if num == 3:
    print "Goodbye"
else:
    while num != 3:
        if num == 1:
            func()
        if num == 2:
            item = raw_input("Please enter the album: ")
            seqentialSearch(albumList, item)
        else:
            print "Invald Input"
```

I have a database that this program is pulling data from. I need it to behave like this:

- If a 1 is entered the program returns the entire contents of the database
- If a 2 is entered I want the program to use sequential search to print all the info about the songs in that album
- If a 3 is entered I just want to print "goodbye"

The two problems I have are:

1. My sequential search code is not returning the right info
2. I would like the program to loop until a 3 is entered.

How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Your `sequentialSearch` function isn't printing anything. And you don't need the `found` variable, you can just `return` from the function when you find the match.

```
def sequentialSearch(albumList, item):
    for i in range(len(albumlist))
        if albumList[i] == item:
            print titleList[i] + ' -- ' + artistList[i] + ' -- ' + albumList[i] + ' --',
            print yearList[i] + ' -- ' + commentList[i]
            return true
    return false
```

In your main code, your `while` loop will never end because you ask for `num` outside the loop. Use:

```
while true:
    num = input("What would you like to do?\n1. Print all the contents of the database\n2. Find all the songs on a particular album\n3. Quit\nPlease Enter 1, 2, or 3: ")
    if num == 3:
        print "Goodbye"
        break
    elif num == 1:
        func()
    elif num == 2:
        item = raw_input("Please enter the album: ")
        sequentialSearch(albumList, item)
    else:
        print "Invald Input"
```

Comment: Thanks guys @barmar your top function returned the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Downloads/Python/Mods/MusicOrganizer.py", line 51, in <module>
    seqentialSearch(albumList, item)
NameError: name 'seqentialSearch' is not defined

Comment: You misspelled `sequential`, you were missing the `u`, and I copied what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to control options as you want:

```
num = 0
while num !=3:
    num = input("What would you like to do?\n1. Print all the contents of the database\n2. Find all the songs on a particular album\n3. Quit\nPlease Enter 1, 2, or 3: ")
    if num == 1:
        func()
    elif num == 2:
        item = raw_input("Please enter the album: ")
        seqentialSearch(albumList, item)
    elif num != 3:
        print "Invald Input"
print "Goodbye"
```